# Bootstrap parent panel is not adjusting the size by adding the child panels in it

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add child  panel horizontally inside in to the parent panel with id "mpdiv". When child panel is increasing, the parent panel is not adjusting and it got hidden.

## CSS:

```
.outer div {

 float: none;

 margin: 1%;
 display: inline-block;
 zoom: 1;
 }
.panel {
 overflow: hidden;
 resize:both;
 position: relative;

  }
```

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" >
 <div class="col-sm-10" >
 <div class="panel panel-default div-responsive "   >
 <div class="panel-body outer div-responsive" id="mpdiv" >

 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

## javascript:

```
var pan='<div  class="panel panel-default text-center"><div     class="panel-
body" ></div>'

function addPanel(){
   $("#mpdiv").append(pan)
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Code is already pasted in my original post. I need the code snippet of, whenever i add the bootstrap child panel in the parent bootstrap panel, parent panel has to adjust right hand side automatically without providing the scroll bar in the parent panel instead  We can have horizonal page scroll bar. Please help me for this requirement.